# simple_nested_form deep nesting issue with link_to_add

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have an issue with simple_nested_form which use deep nesting (nesting form_field within form_field), everything works fine but while adding  field by "link_to_add" it just add parent's fields not added nested fields.

Following are my has_through relationship.

customer.rb

```
has_many :users_customers
has_many :users, :through => :users_customers

accepts_nested_attributes_for :users_customers, allow_destroy: true
```

users_customer.rb

```
belongs_to :customer
   belongs_to :user
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

user.rb

```
has_many :users_customers, foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :customers, :through => :users_customers, :dependent => :destroy
```

Following is my view file code: _form.html.erb under customer view.

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @customer, :validate => true,:html => { class: 'form-horizontal well-white customer-detail', :multipart => 'true' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :users_customers  do |user_cust| %>
    <%= user_cust.fields_for :user do |u| %>
        <%= u.input :first_name,as: :string, label: false, placeholder: 'Enter First Name' %>
       <%= u.input :last_name,as: :string, label: false, placeholder: 'Enter Last Name' %>
    <% end %>
      <%= user_cust.input :role_id, collection: Role.pluck(:name,:id).reject{|t| t[1] == 4 }, label: false, placeholder: 'Select Role' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add User", :users_customers, class: "btn btn-info top-margin"%>
<% end %>
```

Now while click on 'add user' it just add roles dropdown not adding first_name and last_name text box.

Can anyone help me why this happen? or let me know any solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you following the RailsCast on doing this?

Comment: No I did not check it.